# How to Compile .c , .h and .so file with gcc?

Tags: gcc

currently im doing some embedded programing with linux. so i have a host computer Linux ubuntu and my qemu xilinx zynq(virtual).
 to comile normal .c file is simple (bash > arm-xilinxa9-linux-gnueabi-gcc filename.c -g -o outputfilename)

the outputfilename is executable in qemu xilinx zynq.

Now i have 3 type of file hello.c hello.h and hello.so , i hope anyone out there could show me how to compile this 3 file together, Thank you :)

hello.c <--> hello.h <--> hello.so

Answer (score 1):

The example below compiles something and creates an executable. I would suggest to take a look at `Makefile`. The command line makes sense for mini projects but not more.

```
gcc -c -I ../include/something foo.c   
gcc -o prog main.o foo.o -L/usr/local/lib/boo -lboo
```

`.so` is a shared library - probably not what you want.